# using group by or use other function

Tags: php, sql

we all know that using a group by we can eliminate extra column but then what if i wanted to group item A together. objects related to item A will be shown under the heading item A. but when i use a group by, it would only show one line of object under item A. please dont ask me use count. i just need to show all the objects related under item A.

example:

item A:
apple
orange

item B:
pear

the objects would be retrived from a database.
example of codes would be prefered.(:

output:
table format

by year, by type, by batch, by company <--- table name
1997, IT, april, apple.com <---- output of above retrive from db
peter gordon <--- student name retrive from db
jeremy <--- student name retrive from db

1999, enginerring, april, blinkydotcom
regina

Comment: Yes indeed, examples of code would be preferred.

Comment: Can you show us what you would like the output to look like, and the columns in your database? Without this your question is a bit hard to understand

Comment: If you're only getting one row, it means that what you're grouping on has only one distinct set of values.

Comment: but i did try to make all the same value but still one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GROUP_CONCAT() function to group students together into one row, however, that row has to be on the same line as the related data. But when you display it in PHP you can just separate it there.

I tried making a query, but you didn't give much information so it's hard to imagine what you want.

Comment: You always have to put it on the same line, because that's how relational databases work.

Comment: what i mean it, it gave only one result.

Comment: ah, but you have to group it correctly, by using  GROUP BY as well